# How to get public transport time schedule from The Google Maps Directions API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, directions, google-directions-api, transit

I am trying to make public transport time schedule app using **google maps directions api**.

Whats the best way to get **all of the possible** **departure_time**'s for a specific route from one place to another from a specific time?

The problem is, the server is always responding with only one route for one specific time. How can I get all of the following departure_times?

The worst way to do this is asking server every minute if there is some new travel link. But hey, its gonna take a lot of time!

So I thought google might be providing some kind of transport schedules but I can't find any info on google developers webs. I saw only the way to give google schedule information with the help of General Transit Feed Specification (GTFS) [here](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs-realtime/) or [here](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/).

But I can't find the way to get it from them.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe **google maps directions api** will return the information you are looking for as a collection.

The problem with transit data is that calculating a future schedule can require a lot of processing (especially if there are multiple routes involved in the rider reaching their destination) because, basically, the system needs to do a trip plan for each scheduled trip at starting point for the time range.

Google hints at this in their API regarding the `alternatives` parameter

> `alternatives` — If set to true, specifies that the Directions service may provide more than one route alternative in the response. **Note that providing route alternatives may increase the response time from the server.**

Also, the different future departure times may actually be different routes or combination of routes (e.g. where multiple routes may come together on the same street for a while - for instance, near a college campus or other transit hub)

In order to get the underlying route data that would have the actual stop times you are looking for you would need to download the transit agencies' GTFS data directly and process it yourself (check our [GTFS Data Exchange](http://www.gtfs-data-exchange.com/)). This is what your competitors are already doing (e.g. Transit App, Moovit, etc.). There are packages that will do some of this processing for you (e.g. [One Bus Away](http://onebusaway.org/)). However, even with the use of existing libraries, there is some heavy lifting involved here (from a development point of view).

As a final note, if you want to pursue using **google maps directions api** you wouldn't need query it for each minute within a time-range in order to get a series of departure times. You should be able to make a series of calls with the departure time set just past the departure time you got back in the previous call. For example, if the first trip time was 1:00pm set `departure_time` to 1:05pm and request again, then if the second trip time was 1:20pm set the next `departure_time` to 1:25pm and request again, and so on to build your list of future trips.

Answer (score -2):

Okay. Firstly your question is not in the right spirit as stackoverflow demands. Check at google's developer console , API section and check if they offer any such API to give you all transport schedules in 24hrs or not ? If there is any such API then good, you can hit that but if not then I am afraid you wont be able to get it unless you hit API after some intervals.

Another suggestion is that , you can try yahoo or bing maps and check if they have any such API for your query.